# Error with Lua5.3 and LuaL_openlib

Tags: lua

I'm getting this error when trying to require LuaSocket with Lua5.3

> error loading module 'socket.core' from file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so':
>   /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: luaL_openlib

---

Console Output with demonstration:

```
barreeeiroo@Telegram ~/mattata-ai> lua
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local socket = require("socket.core")
> ^C⏎                                                                                                                      
barreeeiroo@Telegram ~/mattata-ai> lua5.3
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local socket = require("socket.core")
error loading module 'socket.core' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so':
        /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: luaL_openlib
stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
> ^C⏎                                                                                                                      
barreeeiroo@Telegram ~/mattata-ai> readelf -a /usr/bin/lua | grep openlib
   109: 0000000000018a70   163 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 luaL_openlib@@LUA_5.2
   240: 0000000000018b20   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 luaL_openlibs@@LUA_5.2
barreeeiroo@Telegram ~/mattata-ai> readelf -a /usr/bin/lua5.3 | grep openlib
   238: 000000000001b330    85 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 luaL_openlibs@@LUA_5.3
```

---

**How can I make luaL_openlib to work with Lua5.3?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [luaL\_openlib replacement for Lua 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041215/lual-openlib-replacement-for-lua-5-2)

Comment: it ran perfectly fine on my machine. Could maybe tell us how you installed socket, and lua?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and solved with this link: https://luarocks.org/

My problem is that I was using lua 5.3 and my luarocks was downloading modules for lua 5.1